# Is an open domain with this property equal to the whole space?

Tags: general-topology

I have a question about a set I came across when solving a problem. We have an open domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ such that: $$ \forall r > 0, \exists x_r \in \Omega \text{ 
 such that  } B(x_r, r)\subset  \Omega.$$
Does this necessarily mean that $\Omega = \mathbb{R}^d$?
I suspect that is the case but I am not too sure about that.

Comment: I believe that it is not necessarily the case: let's take $d=2$ for visualisation. If we just take $\Omega=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2: y>0\}$ this is an open domain. For any $r>0$ just choose the point $x_r = (0, r+1)$ and the whole ball will be contained in the upper half space.

Comment: Thank you @Lukas. I see it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of counterexamples. They can be constructed as follows: pick a sequence $(x_n)\subseteq\mathbb{R}^d$ and then define $U=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty B(x_n,n)$. Then any open subset $\Omega$ containing $U$ will have your property, but it certainly does not have to be whole $\mathbb{R}^d$. For example for $x_n=(n,0,\ldots,0)$ and $U=(0,\infty)\times\mathbb{R}^{d-1}$.